# Sharing Barriers across objects/threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, semaphore, barrier

Lets say I have Object A and Object B. ObjA creates multiple 'ObjB's and keeps a pointer to each, then detaches a thread on each object B to do work. I want to implement a barrier in ObjA that only unlocks whenever all 'ObjB's have reached a certain internal condition within their work functions.

How can I create a barrier with a dynamic count within ObjA, and then make ObjB aware of that barrier so that it can arrive at the barrier? I wanted to use std::barrier but I've had problems trying to do so.

Thus far I cannot make a std::barrier member variable in ObjA because it requires an input size which I will only know once ObjA is constructed. If I create the barrier inside of the busy function of ObjA, then any signal function that ObjB calls to A with won't have scope to it.

Is the best approach to do some homespun semaphore with busy waiting?

Comment: Why do you think a barrier is the proper tool for this? It may be, but my instinct says it's not.

Comment: Make a member variable within ObjA a std::unique_ptr<std::barrier> and instantiate it when you know the expected value.

Comment: @WilliamClements declaring the type of the unique ptr to be barrier causes a compiler error because of missing template arguments.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I wanted to try barrier because it (theoretically) allows every thread to block itself and then unblock automatically when enough of them have reported in, without me having to add room for error with a manually designed semaphore system.

Comment: @Treeman I got that part - but you also added _conditions_ for them to reach the barrier. I'd need to see more of the design behind it but - my initial thought is that you probably should use something else. I'm not sure what unless you show more of the whole idea.

Comment: The basic idea is the B objects  (feeders) generate data for their parent, the 'processor.' The processor waits until the feeders have filled the available space in the processor. Once the feeders detect that they have filled their given data slice, they block until the processor can handle the data. While the processor is waiting for data, it blocks itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a conditional variable.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <condition_variable>
    #include <thread>
    #include <vector>
     
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::mutex cv_m; // This mutex is used for three purposes:
                     // 1) to synchronize accesses to count
                     // 3) for the condition variable cv
    int total_count = 10; // This is count of objBs
    int count = total_count;
     
     
    void obj_b_signals()
    {
        // Do something..
        bool certainCondition = true;
        // We have reached the condition..
        if (certainCondition) {
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
                count--;
            }
            std::cerr << "Notifying...\n";
            cv.notify_one();
        }
    }
     
    int main()
    {
        // obj A logic
       std::vector<std::thread> threads;
       for (size_t i=0; i<total_count; ++i) {
            threads.emplace_back(std::thread(obj_b_signals));
        }
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
            std::cerr << "Waiting for ObjBs to reach a certain condition... \n";
            cv.wait(lk, []{return count == 0;});
            std::cerr << "...finished waiting. count == 0\n";            
        }
        // Do something else
        for (std::thread & t: threads) {
            t.join();
        }
    }
```

Comment: this would unblock main as soon as the first objB reached condition, correct?

Comment: No, each thread decrements the count by 1, and the main thread is waiting for the count to reach 0.

Comment: I ended up using condition variables for the one-to many signals, but couldn't figure out how to use CVs to do the many to one signals. Currently using Atomics for that, though it's a bit buggy. As far as I can tell you cannot use barriers across scope limits because they are const expr, but I would love to be wrong.